# FFmpeg and pressing d during encode, how to continue?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am encoding a huge video which takes forever. I'm using Windows and a command prompt. And I accidentally pressed d while the window was active. That seems to have triggered some kind of debug mode. Typing ? does not reveal what d is (different from D) and I can't find a way to continue.

How do I continue the encoding?

I wish there was a much clearer documentation about this function, and all functions stopping/pausing should have an easy way to continue encoding and making sure you really want to stop.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it should continue to encode normally.

Comment: Yes, thank you, works!